# Is it necessary to encrypt a swap * file * if it will reside on an encrypted root filesytem?

Tags: encryption, swap

I'm running Linux on my Laptop and wish to protect my data in case the machine is lost or stolen.

I've configured an encrypted ArchLinux environment and have everything working the way that I want. Now I wish to add suspend to disk functionality, which necessitates swap space. If I allocate swap space as *a **file** on the root filesystem* (which is already encrypted), does that swap **file** still need to be encrypted? Please explain why or why not.

Comment: What did you use to encrypt the root filesystem?

Comment: The disk is encrypted using dm-crypt and LUKS following the guide here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Simple_partition_layout_with_LUKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the root filesystem is encrypted, all files written to the filesystem, whether they be plain text files or swap files will all be encrypted.

Comment: So there is no technical or security-related reason for further encrypting the swap file as well?

Comment: Indeed.  No need to encrypt it further.